# Multiple SQL Join with override

Tags: sql, database-performance, recursive-query

Let's say I have a table that represents documents, with a composite primary key: an id and a version. Multiple versions of a document can exist in the table at the same time.

```
create table document (id bigint not null, version int not null, 
    data varchar(255), primary key(id, version));
```

There's another table that contains a hierarchy of views. (I'm leaving out foreign keys and other constraints in this example, but they'd apply).

```
create table view (id bigint primary key, parent_id bigint);
```

And another table that contains rows that each relate a view to a set of documents. Assume that there's a unique constraint on view_doc.view_id and view_doc.doc_id, so that a given document may not appear more than once in a given view.

```
create table view_doc (id bigint primary key, view_id bigint not null, 
    doc_id bigint not null, doc_version int);
```

Logically, a view contains all of the document/versions it defines. A child view (which has a non-null view.parent_id) contains all the document/versions in its parent, plus any documents in itself. If different versions of a document are defined in a child view and its parent, only the version of that document specified in the child view should be visible. If a document is specified in a child view with a NULL doc_version, the document should be considered as not existing in that child view, even if it exists in its parent.

I'd like to build SQL that given a view.id will give me a list of all the documents and their respective versions in the view, as defined by the rules above (whether it is a child view or not). I know that this could ultimately result in a recursive query, but would be willing to accept a strict two-level hierarchy as well (in other words, a child view's parent_id could always be assumed to be null) if that simplifies things.

I need to represent this in Oracle, DB2, and SQL Server. It needn't be the exact same query in all three databases, though that would certainly be nice.

How would you write this query so that it runs quickly?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  And could we get some sample data/results?  To my knowledge, it _can't_ be the same in the RDBMSs you list (Oracle doesn't have `BIGINT`, although equivalents can be contructed), although they'll likely share much of the same structure.

Comment: You don't really sound like you know what you want.  For example, do you want a full hierarchy of views or not?  Do you want a query/database structure that is fully portable or not?  How fast do you need your query to run?  How many records will you have (More than 2 billion documents?  really??)  Not only that but these constraints are somewhat mutually exclusive, or at least there are trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

The way different DBMSs handle recursion is quite different.  Here is a working query that is specifically for SQL server and is not necessarily fast.  (Note that sql server limits recursion nesting to 100 levels unless you apply a query hint):

```
--Flatten views
;with thisView as (
    select ID, 0 as nestingLevel, parent_ID
    from #view
    where id = @viewID
union all
    select v.ID, tv.nestingLevel + 1 as nestingevel, v.parent_ID
    from #view v
        inner join thisView tv on v.ID = tv.parent_id
),--Determine documents/versions to present
docSets as (
    select doc_ID, doc_version, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by doc_id order by nestingLevel) as docSequence
    from #view_Doc
        inner join thisView tv on view_id = tv.ID
)--filter documents
select *
from docSets
where docSequence = 1
    and doc_version is not null;
```

You mention speed at the end of your question, but you don't give any of the details necessary to determine what the best way to achieve speed would be.  Using recursion is generally not very efficient in Sql Server.  Further, the most efficient approach might be different between DBMS.  For Sql Server 2008, look up the HierarchyID data type: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37171/HierarchyID-Data-Type-in-SQL-Server-2008